# Referring to Dumped LinkedIn API data

Tags: rest, python-2.7, linkedin-api, pickle

Quick problem here that I don't know how to solve and thought you guys could give me a heads-up on which way to go. I have successfully pulled all my connection data using the LinkedIn REST API both in XML and JSON and dumped them (the former using the cPickle plugin). The issue is that I need to refer to a single field within the data and so decided to use XML as it seemed to be the easiest one to use by far. When I refer to the specific field in my .pickle file, it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'location'
```

However, opening the pickle file with notepad, I can see that all my connections do have their location field stored in the XML format. It's very strange!

Here's my referral code:

```
import cPickle

connections_data = 'linkedin_connections.pickle'
response = cPickle.load(open(connections_data))

print response

locations = [ec.location for ec in response]
```

I have a print function set up to show what's in my file and all of the data appears as a normal XML output using the people call of the REST API. The XML data appears as follows:

```
<person>
<id>ID_number</id>
<first-name>blah</first-name>
<last-name>blah</last-name>
<headline>Business Development and Sales Executive at Computaris</headline>
<picture-url>picture_url</picture-url>
<api-standard-profile-request>
  <url>profile_request</url>
  <headers total="1">
    <http-header>
      <name>x-li-auth-token</name>
      <value>name</value>
    </http-header>
  </headers>
</api-standard-profile-request>
<site-standard-profile-request>
  <url>request_url</url>
</site-standard-profile-request>
<location>
  <name>location</name>
  <country>
    <code>country_code</code>
  </country>
</location>
<industry>industry</industry>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.